# Why it only realize the last instance when using python singleton pattern

Tags: python, singleton

the code is in belows:

```
class A(object):
    __instance = None

    def __new__(cls, *args, **kwargs):
        if cls.__instance is None:
            cls.__instance = object.__new__(cls)
            return cls.__instance
        else:
            return cls.__instance

    def __init__(self, book):
        self.book = book

    def pr(self):
        print(self.book)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    b = A("wind")
    a = A("good")
    print(a is b)
    print(a.pr())
    print(b.pr())
```

the result is

```
True
good
None
good
None
```

why the result is not:

```
True
wind
good
```

where is wrong with the code?

Comment: It `a` is `b` how should `pr()` return different values?

Comment: The wind is the first instance. Why it not `True wind wind`,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for each time of call `A()`, its `__init__` will be invoked, as it is a singleton, the `__init__()` method invoked twice on the same object.
you could get your expected result with:

```
b = A("wind")
b.pr()
a = A("good")
a.pr()
print(a is b)
```